# %env magic command not properly expanding environment variables in Google Colab

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, google-colaboratory

Setting environment variables in Google Colab with %env doesn't seem to properly expand existing environment variables when prefixed by $:

```
> !echo $PATH
/usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/tools/node/bin:/tools/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/opt/bin

> %env PATH=$PATH
env: PATH=$PATH

> !echo PATH
PATH
```

I don't think setting environment variables with !export works either. Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: In Colab, `%env` lines do not evaluate shell variables, they only evaluate Python variables.
If you do `%env PATH=$PATH` you will have given the shell variable `$PATH` a new value.. `$PATH`.
So if you did `!echo $PATH`, you would get the output: `$PATH`
But because you do `!echo PATH` you just get `PATH` as you would in any terminal.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
!echo $PATH
OLD_ENV_PATH = %env PATH
%env PATH=$OLD_ENV_PATH:/test
!echo $PATH
```

`%env` uses python expansion, so you need to store value for env variable in some python variable, and then set env var referencing it.